# How to navigate and update fields inside a complex json object in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How do I update the value of "message" belonging to "chatTemplateId":"5" and "mid":"b" to "Test2" in below json in node-js/javascript.I would have used LINQ in C# but not sure how to get this accomplished in the most optimised way in javascript/nodejs

```
{
    "chatTemplate" : "defaultTemplate",
    "chatTemplates" :[
        {
            "chatTemplateId": "5",
            "messages" : [
                {
                    "mid" : "a",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "b",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "c",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "d",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                }
            ]        
        },
        {
            "chatTemplateId": "4",
            "messages" : [
                {
                    "mid" : "a",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "b",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "c",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "d",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                }
            ]        
        }
    ]   
}
```

Comment: Can you add the linq/C# code you'd have written, please? And maybe an attempt at a non-optimised JS version?

Comment: For the non optimised version in js, I could have used two loops and gone and checked each block inside and updated where the value met.

Comment: You *need* two loops to process a structure nested two levels deep, there's no way around that. Not in C# either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a single element of an array in place, use the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method and provide a callback that tests whether the element is the desired one.

```js
const data =
{
    "chatTemplate" : "defaultTemplate",
    "chatTemplates" :[
        {
            "chatTemplateId": "5",
            "messages" : [
                {
                    "mid" : "a",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "b",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "c",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "d",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "chatTemplateId": "4",
            "messages" : [
                {
                    "mid" : "a",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "b",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "c",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "d",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

data.chatTemplates
.find(obj => obj.chatTemplateId === '5').messages
.find(obj => obj.mid === 'b').message
= 'Test2';

console.log(data);
```

Comment: this looks like a better solution +1

Answer (score 1):

I did using the [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```js
let a = {
    "chatTemplate" : "defaultTemplate",
    "chatTemplates" :[
        {
            "chatTemplateId": "5",
            "messages" : [
                {
                    "mid" : "a",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "b",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "c",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "d",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                }
            ]        
        },
        {
            "chatTemplateId": "4",
            "messages" : [
                {
                    "mid" : "a",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "b",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "c",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "d",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                }
            ]        
        }
    ]   
}

function updateMessage(obj,chatTemplateId,mid,message){
    let chatTemplateIndex = obj.chatTemplates.findIndex(i => i.chatTemplateId === chatTemplateId);
    let messageIndex = obj.chatTemplates[chatTemplateIndex].messages.findIndex(i => i.mid === mid);
    obj.chatTemplates[chatTemplateIndex].messages[messageIndex].message = message;
}

updateMessage(a,'5','b','Test2')

console.log(a)
```

**EDIT**: If want to update all messages with a given mid can try something like this

```js
let a = {
    "chatTemplate" : "defaultTemplate",
    "chatTemplates" :[
        {
            "chatTemplateId": "5",
            "messages" : [
                {
                    "mid" : "a",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "b",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "c",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "d",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                }
            ]        
        },
        {
            "chatTemplateId": "4",
            "messages" : [
                {
                    "mid" : "a",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "b",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "c",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                },
                {
                    "mid" : "d",
                    "message" : "Test1"
                }
            ]        
        }
    ]   
}

function updateMessages(obj,mid,message){
    obj.chatTemplates.map((el)=> {
    let messageIndex = el.messages.findIndex(i => i.mid === mid);
    if(messageIndex!=-1){ //precaution if not all message arrays have the given mid value
         el.messages[messageIndex].message = message
    }
    return;
  })
 }

updateMessages(a,'b','Test2')

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks helpful. How would have I changed if I had to update all "message" with "mid" : "a" , that is no role of chatTemplateId

Comment: @SugarCode hi i did some edit. is that what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the first object of the array, where `chatTemplateId: 5`. The first object is always at 0 index in the array. Then you access the `messages` array inside the `chatTemplates` array and select the second element which is at index 1.

```
chatTemplates[0].messages[1].message = "Test 2"
```

Comment: No. It is not known ahead of time that these values are going to be at 0 index and 1 index.

Comment: can you share the code of the function generating that JSON? Then, I can look into your code and suggest a solution.